# kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)

Tags: boot, kernel, mount

OK, so I have fallen down a rabbit hole without much of a back up plan so I am hoping someone will be able to guide me through recovering my Linux install. I have limited knowledge of linux systems and Ubuntu so it's probably what has got me in the mess in the first place so will try and best explain what has happened so far.

So I needed to clear space in /boot as Webmin was reported low storage.

`uname -a` reported 4.4.0-137-generic as my current kernal.

I ran a similar command as this, making sure the current kernel wasn't listed:

```
sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'|awk '{ if ($1=="ii") print $2}'|grep -v `uname -r`
```

This as now left me with 4.4.0-137-generic, 4.4.0-138-generic and 4.4.0-139-generic, however none of them boot as I get the following error:

> kernel panic-not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown
>   block(0,0)

I have tried the chroot options below:

```
sudo fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sdax /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
```

However after I mount sda1 I can't go any further, mnt shows the /boot folder and I can mount the dev folder as they don't exist in /mnt.

I have tried the following when I was able to boot in to 4.4.0-137-generic and a few other options:

```
update-initramfs -u -k 4.4.0-137-generic
```

Which hasn't resolved the issue, I used to be able to see the GRUB menu for recovery options however that is no longer showing, I am currently getting in to tty which is showing 4.4.0-139-generic when running the `uname -a` command.

This is my first post so excuse incorrect formatting and the lack of information for steps taken, might have been a little gun ho with this all. Let me know if I can amend anything for future reference.

---

So to follow up, found my root partition is under `/dev/mapper/Server--vg-root` and I was able to mount all the folders for `chroot` however the recovery CD was 32-bit and need 64 which is my next step.

However the folder `/dev/mapper/Server--vg-root/boot` is empty, though `/dev/boot` is not. Do I need to mount it using the following command or am I supposed to be repairing `/dev/mapper/Server--vg-root/boot` to contain items?

```
sudo mount --bind /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
```

Or how do I check which folder Grub is using to confirm which one needs repairing?

Comment: To /mnt directory you should mount your root partition, not boot. The boot partition you should mount to /mnt/boot after mounting rootfs firstly. After this steps, the rest you have should be ok and after chroot'ing you can just reinstall the kernel package and try boot this system.

Comment: Is there an alternative command for that? "sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt" is the command I am using but only seems to mount the contents of /boot, I am not sure if I am running a setup that's not resulting in the expected outcome?

Comment: Not to worry, just going to work through the following link as I suspect I have an LVM setup:

"Finding your root partition"
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation and understanding that my system differs from a lot of online instructions as it was configured using LVM, reinstalling older kernals etc. The system appears to be booting without issue, some of my issues might not have been issues at all just ignorant to the setup of "seeing" GRUB boot and console not loading.

One thing that did assist was Super-Grub2-disk here as it confirmed my Ubuntu installation would load- https://www.supergrubdisk.org/

Now for a bit of a tidy up of my system after learning what I have.

A few things to note:
ESC shows the Grub menu on my system, not SHIFT.
To show my console use CTRL+ALT+F1 to load the TTY1 console, I need to update my GRUB config install to bypass this.